# Checking R list elements with common names

Tags: r

I have a nested R list with the following structure:

```
my_list <- list(a = list(value = 1, alert = FALSE), b = list(value = 2, alert = FALSE), c = list(value = 3, alert = TRUE))
```

Is there logic to determine whether all the elements named `alert` are FALSE? For example:

```
ifelse(<all mylist["alerts"] are FALSE>, print("No alerts to report!"), print("ALERT"))

> ALERT
```

Comment: Use `!any(vapply(my_list, \`[[\`, NA, "alert"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with `sapply`

In the general case

```
ifelse(all(sapply(my_list, function(x) x["alert"]==F)),
  "No alerts to report!","ALERT")
[1] "ALERT"
```

Using the logical values directly as pointed out by @Ritchie Sacramento

```
ifelse(any(sapply(my_list, function(x) !x["alert"][[1]])),
  "ALERT", "No alerts to report!")
[1] "ALERT"
```

Comment: Consider `if (any(sapply(my_list, \`[[\`, "alert"))) "Alert" else "No alert"` - using a "boolean is equal to boolean" comparison is very clunky.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Valid point, I put it in as an additional option!

Comment: Great - although I meant we should look to avoid constructs such as `x["alert"]==F` -  `x[["alert"]]` is already a boolean value so can be used directly.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Ah, gotcha!

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table::rbindlist`:

```r
c("NO ALERT", "ALERT")[1+1*any(data.table::rbindlist(my_list)$alert)]

#> [1] "ALERT"
```